# Прямая ссылка на всплывающее окно сделанное с помощью плагина Popup Maker

Tags: wordpress, popup

На сайте, созданном на **CMS Wordpress**, есть всплывающее окно с формой записи, которое реализовано с помощью плагина **Popup Maker**. Так вот, все работает идеально, но очень хочется сделать прямую ссылку на это всплывающее окно, а именно, чтобы я мог *отправить ссылку какому-либо пользователю* и он при переходе по ней видел главную страничку сайта и сразу же всплывающее окно.

К сожалению, на данный момент, при переходе по ссылке с добавлением класса popup открывается просто главная страница...

Comment: Если Popup Maker не обладает такой возможностью то скорее всего никак.

Comment: Обладает. Пишут, что это возможно, но не нашел ни одного примера, как это сделать...

Comment: значит см документацию к плагину.